# WP_Query | Help me create a search term with an 'OR' relation?

Tags: php, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I have written a very elaborate script that will essentially allow the user to select from categories, tags and of course the search term. Then run these parameters through a WP_Query.

I can successfully achieve the results I want using the 'AND' relation, this works for when the user populates search parameters into all fields; search term, tags & categories. It will also work for leaving one of the three parameters blank, two of the parameters blank and will return all products when all parameters are left blank.

I am then trying to add in an option to use the relation 'OR'. Where it will allow them to still add in the three search parameters however the results should only have to apply to one of the parameters. This works if the user only selects from tags and categories, however it doesn't return the correct results if they use the search term parameter.

I believe this to be because the relation is only set to the tags and categories, I need this to be extended to the search term too.

Hopefully you can grasp what I am trying to achieve, in my snippet you can assume all variables populating are correct, I simply wish to ask for help adding the search term as a parameter with the relation 'OR'. Here is my current WP_Query:

```
$paged              = !empty($_POST['page'])                ? $_POST['page']                : 1;
$display_count      = !empty($_POST['display_count'])       ? $_POST['display_count']       : 9;
$direction          = !empty($_POST['direction'])           ? $_POST['direction']           : '';
$search_term        = !empty($_POST['search_term'])         ? $_POST['search_term']         : '';
$search_tags        = !empty($_POST['search_tags'])         ? $_POST['search_tags']         : '';
$search_categories  = !empty($_POST['search_categories'])   ? $_POST['search_categories']   : '';
$search_relation    = !empty($_POST['search_relation'])     ? $_POST['search_relation']     : 'AND';

$offset_modifier    = 0;
if      ($direction     === 'prev') :
    $offset_modifier        = $paged - 2;
elseif  ($direction     === 'next') :
    $offset_modifier        = $paged;
elseif  ($direction     === 'last') :
    $offset_modifier        = $paged - 1;
endif;
$offsetcalc = $offset_modifier * $display_count;

$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'    => $display_count,
    'page'              => $paged,
    'offset'            => $offsetcalc,
    'tax_query'         => array()
);

if ( $search_term != '' ) :
    $args['s'] = $search_term;
endif;

if ( $search_tags != '' ) :
    $args['tax_query']['product_tag'] = array(
        'taxonomy'          => 'product_tag',
        'field'             => 'slug',
        'terms'             => array($search_tags),
    );

    if (strpos($search_tags, ', ') !== false) {
        $args['tax_query']['product_tag']['relation'] = $search_relation;
    }
endif;

if ( $search_categories != '' ) :
    $args['tax_query']['product_cat'] = array(
        'taxonomy'          => 'product_cat',
        'field'             => 'slug',
        'terms'             => array($search_categories),
    );

    if (strpos($search_categories, ', ') !== false) {
        $args['tax_query']['product_cat']['relation'] = $search_relation;
    }
endif;

if ( $search_tags != '' && $search_categories != '' ) :
    $args['tax_query']['relation'] = $search_relation;
endif;

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
```

So trying my best to adapt this to have the relation of 'OR' on the search term (note the "if($search_term != ''):" and the change to the "$args['tax_query']['relation'] = $search_relation;" IF statement):

```
$paged              = !empty($_POST['page'])                ? $_POST['page']                : 1;
$display_count      = !empty($_POST['display_count'])       ? $_POST['display_count']       : 9;
$direction          = !empty($_POST['direction'])           ? $_POST['direction']           : '';
$search_term        = !empty($_POST['search_term'])         ? $_POST['search_term']         : '';
$search_tags        = !empty($_POST['search_tags'])         ? $_POST['search_tags']         : '';
$search_categories  = !empty($_POST['search_categories'])   ? $_POST['search_categories']   : '';
$search_relation    = !empty($_POST['search_relation'])     ? $_POST['search_relation']     : 'AND';

$offset_modifier    = 0;
if      ($direction     === 'prev') :
    $offset_modifier        = $paged - 2;
elseif  ($direction     === 'next') :
    $offset_modifier        = $paged;
elseif  ($direction     === 'last') :
    $offset_modifier        = $paged - 1;
endif;
$offsetcalc = $offset_modifier * $display_count;

$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'    => $display_count,
    'page'              => $paged,
    'offset'            => $offsetcalc,
    'tax_query'         => array()
);

if ( $search_term != '' ) :
    $args['tax_query']['product_tit'] = array(
        'taxonomy'          => 'product_tit',
        'field'             => 'slug',
        'terms'             => $search_term,
    );
endif;

if ( $search_tags != '' ) :
    $args['tax_query']['product_tag'] = array(
        'taxonomy'          => 'product_tag',
        'field'             => 'slug',
        'terms'             => array($search_tags),
    );

    if (strpos($search_tags, ', ') !== false) {
        $args['tax_query']['product_tag']['relation'] = $search_relation;
    }
endif;

if ( $search_categories != '' ) :
    $args['tax_query']['product_cat'] = array(
        'taxonomy'          => 'product_cat',
        'field'             => 'slug',
        'terms'             => array($search_categories),
    );

    if (strpos($search_categories, ', ') !== false) {
        $args['tax_query']['product_cat']['relation'] = $search_relation;
    }
endif;

if ((isset($search_term) && isset($search_tags)) || (isset($search_term) && isset($search_categories)) || (isset($search_tags) && isset($search_categories))) :
    $args['tax_query']['relation'] = $search_relation;
endif;

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
```

My changes do not allow for the search term parameter to work, I imagine I am using the wrong methodology or the wrong taxonomy name 'product_tit'...

**Please help me create the search term as a parameter with the 'OR' relation and ensure it is narrowed down to the products title only**

Can anyone help?

Really appreciative of contributors, Jason.

*EDIT*: Latest code that doesn't work with the 'OR' relation.

```
// PRODUCT PAGINATION AJAX FUNCTION
    function load_products_by_ajax_callback() {
        $paged              = !empty($_POST['page'])                ? $_POST['page']                : 1;
        $display_count      = !empty($_POST['display_count'])       ? $_POST['display_count']       : 9;
        $direction          = !empty($_POST['direction'])           ? $_POST['direction']           : '';
        $search_term        = !empty($_POST['search_term'])         ? $_POST['search_term']         : '';
        $search_tags        = !empty($_POST['search_tags'])         ? $_POST['search_tags']         : '';
        $search_categories  = !empty($_POST['search_categories'])   ? $_POST['search_categories']   : '';
        $search_relation    = !empty($_POST['search_relation'])     ? $_POST['search_relation']     : 'AND';

        $offset_modifier    = 0;
        if      ($direction     === 'prev') :
            $offset_modifier        = $paged - 2;
        elseif  ($direction     === 'next') :
            $offset_modifier        = $paged;
        elseif  ($direction     === 'last') :
            $offset_modifier        = $paged - 1;
        endif;
        $offsetcalc = $offset_modifier * $display_count;

        $args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'product',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
            'order'             => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page'    => $display_count,
            'page'              => $paged,
            'offset'            => $offsetcalc >= 1 ? $offsetcalc : '',
            'tax_query'         => array()
        );

        // Parse the search tags/categories list into an array.
        $tags               = strlen( $search_tags )            ? wp_parse_slug_list( $search_tags )        : '';
        $cats               = strlen( $search_categories )      ? wp_parse_slug_list( $search_categories )  : '';
        $has_search_term    = ( strlen( $search_term ) > 0 );
        $relation           = strtoupper( trim( $search_relation ) ); // normalize it into all caps

        // We don't use $args['s']. Instead, we write our own custom SQL for searching
        // in the post title only. We also don't use the tax_query parameter (anymore).
        // This is basically $args['tax_query'], except that we *don't* add it to $args.
        $tax_query = array();

        if ( ! empty( $search_tags ) ) {
            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'product_tag',
                'terms'     => wp_parse_slug_list( $search_tags ),
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'operator'  => $search_relation,
            );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $search_categories ) ) {
            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
                'terms'     => wp_parse_slug_list( $search_categories ),
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'operator'  => $search_relation,
            );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $tax_query ) ) { // if empty, don't set the relation
            $tax_query['relation'] = $search_relation;
        }

        $_filter = true; // a (private) var for the closure below
        add_filter( 'posts_clauses',
        function ( $clauses ) use ( &$_filter, $search_term, $tax_query ) {
            if ( ! $_filter ) {
                return $clauses;
            }

            global $wpdb;

            $search_where = '';
            if ( $search_term ) {
                $like  = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $search_term ) . '%';
                $search_where = $wpdb->prepare( "$wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE %s", $like );
            }

            if ( ! empty( $tax_query ) ) {
                $tax_query = new WP_Tax_Query( $tax_query );
                $is_and = ( 'AND' === $tax_query->relation );

                $tax_query = $tax_query->get_sql( $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );
                if ( empty( $tax_query['where'] ) ) { // just in case..
                    if ( $search_where ) {
                        $clauses['where'] .= " AND ( $search_where )";
                    }
                    return $clauses;
                }

                $clauses['join'] .= $tax_query['join'];
                if ( $is_and ) {
                    $clauses['where'] .= $search_where ?
                        " AND ( $search_where ) {$tax_query['where']}" :
                        $tax_query['where'];
                } else {
                    $where = preg_replace( '/^ *AND\b/', '', $tax_query['where'] );
                    $clauses['where'] .= $search_where ?
                        " AND ( ( $search_where ) OR{$where} )" :
                        $tax_query['where'];
                }
                $clauses['groupby'] = "$wpdb->posts.ID";
            } elseif ( $search_where ) {
                $clauses['where'] .= " AND ( $search_where )";
            }

            return $clauses;
        } );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        $_filter = false;
    
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

            woocommerce_product_loop_start();

            echo '<div id="product-list" class="product-list">';

                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

                    $the_query->the_post();

                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'productloop' );

                endwhile;

            echo '</div>';

            woocommerce_product_loop_end();

        else :

            echo '<div class="no-search-results">This search returned no results, please refine your parameters!</div>';

        endif;

        $product_loop_count = $the_query->found_posts;
        echo '<div class="product-list-count">';
            echo '<div class="product-loop-count-text">Total product count:&nbsp;</div><div id="product-loop-count">' . $product_loop_count . '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        
        wp_die();
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_load_products_by_ajax', 'load_products_by_ajax_callback');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_products_by_ajax', 'load_products_by_ajax_callback');
// END PRODUCT PAGINATION AJAX FUNCTION
```

Comment: Try removing the `if` with that `$args['tax_query']['relation']` and just use `'tax_query' => array( 'relation' => $search_relation )` in your `$args`.

Comment: I think I need to fix this snippet too... $args['tax_query']['product_tit'] = array('taxonomy' => 'product_tit',

Comment: Well maybe, why did you add it there? Is `product_tit` a valid taxonomy? And do the `$search_tags` and `$search_categories` hold a single term slug or multiple slugs?

Comment: It is not valid, this is half of the question really c: The tags will be a comma seperated string so it could be multiple categories , multiple tags, or multiples of both.

Comment: I don't have an answer now, but you should understand the differences between the `relation` and `operator` [parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_tax_query/__construct/#parameters); they shouldn't be both set to `$search_relation`. Instead, you could add another field like `$terms_relation`.

Comment: I said that because in the linked question, I could see you're setting both the `relation` and `operator` parameters to `$search_relation`. But did you actually do that because you're trying to be able to query for posts that 1) match the search term; or 2) are in the chosen tags; or 3) are in the chosen categories? I.e. Posts that match any of those 3 criteria.

Comment: Are you able to help me create the search term as a parameter I can use? I understand the difference between relation and operator, but this won't help me create a relation of 'OR' on the search term. Please would you mind just double glance the change I have made between the two code blocks and see if you are able to think of the way I set up the arg for search term.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104913/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-jason-is-my-name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***(Revised on March 25 2020 UTC)***

So in this revised answer, I'll just begin with the code:

1. Define the variables: (I intentionally included only the `$args` part)

   ```php
   // define POSTed/submitted variables here like $paged, $display_count and $direction

   // define the offset/'direction' stuff here

   // then define your $args array
   $args = array(
       'post_type'      => 'product',
       'post_status'    => 'publish',
       'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
       'order'          => 'ASC',
       'posts_per_page' => $display_count,
       // You should use 'paged' and not 'page'.
       'paged'          => $paged,
       'offset'         => $offsetcalc >= 1 ? $offsetcalc : '',
       'tax_query'      => array(),
   );
   ```
2. And here's the main code, for the "search term OR":

   ```php
   // This is basically $args['tax_query'], except that we *don't* add it to $args.
   $tax_query = array();

   if ( ! empty( $search_tags ) ) {
       $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
           'terms'    => wp_parse_slug_list( $search_tags ),
           'field'    => 'slug',
       );
   }

   if ( ! empty( $search_categories ) ) {
       $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
           'terms'    => wp_parse_slug_list( $search_categories ),
           'field'    => 'slug',
       );
   }

   if ( ! empty( $tax_query ) ) { // if empty, don't set the relation
       $tax_query['relation'] = $search_relation;
   }

   $_filter = true; // a (private) var for the closure below
   add_filter( 'posts_clauses',
   function ( $clauses ) use ( &$_filter, $search_term, $tax_query ) {
       if ( ! $_filter ) {
           return $clauses;
       }

       global $wpdb;

       $search_where = '';
       if ( $search_term ) {
           $like  = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $search_term ) . '%';
           $search_where = $wpdb->prepare( "$wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE %s", $like );
       }

       if ( ! empty( $tax_query ) ) {
           $tax_query = new WP_Tax_Query( $tax_query );
           $is_and = ( 'AND' === $tax_query->relation );

           $tax_query = $tax_query->get_sql( $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );
           if ( empty( $tax_query['where'] ) ) { // just in case..
               if ( $search_where ) {
                   $clauses['where'] .= " AND ( $search_where )";
               }
               return $clauses;
           }

           $clauses['join'] .= $tax_query['join'];
           if ( $is_and ) {
               $clauses['where'] .= $search_where ?
                                    " AND ( $search_where ) {$tax_query['where']}" :
                                    $tax_query['where'];
           } else {
               $where = preg_replace( '/^ *AND\b/', '', $tax_query['where'] );
               $clauses['where'] .= $search_where ?
                                    " AND ( ( $search_where ) OR{$where} )" :
                                    $tax_query['where'];
           }
           $clauses['groupby'] = "$wpdb->posts.ID";
       } elseif ( $search_where ) {
           $clauses['where'] .= " AND ( $search_where )";
       }

       return $clauses;
   } );

   $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
   $_filter = false; // disable the filter, to avoid issues with other WP_Query calls
   ```

### A bit of explanation (for code #2 above)

What you're looking for is a `WHERE` clause that looks something like:

*(There are other conditions/variations, but this is the main one)*

```sql
WHERE post_type = 'product' AND (
  ( post_title LIKE '%<search term>%' ) # Find posts that matched the search term,
  OR ( product_tag IN (<ids/slugs>) )   # ..or those that are in the specified tags
  OR ( product_cat IN (<ids/slugs>) )   # ..or categories.
)
```

So in that code #2 above, I'm using the [`posts_clauses` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_clauses/) to add that `WHERE` clause (and do other relevant stuff), but for generating the proper SQL clauses for the taxonomy (tag/category) queries, I'm using [`WP_Tax_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_tax_query/) (which is what `WP_Query` uses, btw).

### Additional Notes

1. I'm using [`wp_parse_slug_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_slug_list/) to parse the (comma-separated) tags and categories into an array of slugs. And you should also be using it to make sure we have a *valid array* and because the function just works well. :)
2. Remember that if `offset` is `0`, then in the `$args`, the `offset` should be set to `''` (i.e. an empty string) instead of `0`, to make sure the `$paged` works as expected.
3. Just a personal note... sorry, I forgot about using `WP_Tax_Query` before. ;)

Comment: I am already passing the tags and categories as a comma separated string? The values gathered are placed in by a wp function, so these are always going to be correct. Please can we adapt this to use the strings provided by the $_POST[variables] :s

Comment: Have you already tried the code? What issue(s) you get with using `wp_parse_slug_list()`? And I am indeed using the `$_POST` variables/values; e.g. the `wp_parse_slug_list( $search_tags )` - that `$search_tags` is the one as in `$search_tags = !empty($_POST['search_tags']) ? $_POST['search_tags'] : '';`. I intentionally didn't include the variable definitions in my code, but in your code, they should be included.

Comment: This is a massive step forwards one tiny step back you may be able to help me search through strictly the title of each product, I believe it is actually working now, but I was thrown off as it searches product content too so wasn't returning what I predicted to begin with, my apologies.

Comment: Okay, but I don't really understand that... and if there's any part of the code that may look scary/complex to you..., feel free to ask. :) And I should make this one thing clear to you: In your code in the question, you used `array($search_tags)`, and `wp_parse_slug_list( $search_tags )` will basically do the same, but even better - if `$search_tags`'s value is `one, two` (i.e. two slugs), then `array( $search_tags )` will return `array( 'one, two' )`, but `wp_parse_slug_list()` gives you `array( 'one', 'two' )` which is the correct one - unless `one, two` is actually a single slug..

Comment: Answer updated. But sorry, just delete that `$has_search_term = ( strlen( $search_term ) > 0 );` - it's not in use anymore.

Comment: I need a little bit more help with this I think :s I have added in some further functionality so that I can narrow down results in the address bar, but it has identified that some products show when the 'AND' relation is used, when they should be filtered out. The products in this result: https://development.materialshub.com/?phrase=aluminium+category=ceramics+tag=aesthetic shouldn't show as they do not have the tag 'Aesthetic' associated in the back-end. Are you free to help me analyze why this might be?

Comment: The tags that are associated with the first product in those results are: low cost, thermal shock resistant & versatile. I think it doesn't use the 'AND' relation for tags and categories..?

Comment: Good call, it is most likely something I have changed in the script that passes the variables to this script. I will have to investigate that first!

Comment: There is definitely something not right, I have scrapped through the code and I am convinced it is something within the function. I will write up a new question so you are able to be rewarded for your efforts again c:

Comment: Hey Jason. :) So this is quite embarrassing.. but back then, you confirmed the code was working, so I ignored one thing (or a possible issue) I actually noticed in the code - the `IN()` part, basically. So could you please just delete the other question - we can continue here. And if it's alright to you, can we delete all our (own) previous comments?

Comment: Anything you would like. I do appreciate a tidy workspace!

Comment: All cleared up! Keep me updated on what I should be changing c:

Comment: I actually meant all comments posted since Feb 26 :) But we can clear the comments later, after you done testing the updated code - and make sure to test thoroughly this time! =) And you do know how/where to make the changes, right? Just put code #2 after the variables are defined. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Tested, I am not sure this also quite works. If I am using the 'AND' relation and have multiple tags or categories; it doesn't restrict the result to require both. An example would be selecting from the categories 'glass' & 'green'. Which returns lots of products that only have one applicable category. Similar situation for tags, if you narrow down the search term to aluminium, then add the tags 'filtration' & 'impact resistant' you get one product returned which is great, but then if you add a third tag 'corrosion resistant' it will return 5 results when this should return zero results.

Comment: In each of the tax queries, i.e. the `$tax_query[]` arrays, try setting the `operator` to the search relation - e.g. `$tax_query[] = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 'operator' => $search_relation, ... );` Which means, if the search relation is `AND`, whenever two or more categories and/or tags are selected, WordPress will search for posts that are in *all* of the selected categories/tags. If the relation is `OR`, then WordPress will only check *any* of the categories/tags.

Comment: This worked c: Cheers for revisiting!

Comment: the 'OR' is no longer working again. Are you able to help me? I cannot figure out a way to DM you, so this is a swing in the dark...

Comment: I have updated my question with the latest code in use, are you able to see where this is bugged? @Sally